# Java - Loop to average rgb values should be breaking things....but isn't

Tags: java, arrays, loops

So I've got a school project and we have to work with a couple classes our prof gave us and make our own to make an image organizer.

The first part consists of making a set of static methods to edit the images themselves as 2D arrays of Color arrays(ColorImage type).

The first first problem is making a tool to downscale an image by a factor of f(f sided square of pixels in the original becomes 1 pixel in the output), and mine works, but I think it shouldn't and I can't figure why it works, so any help is appreciated. Specifically I'm taking about the loop that averages the colours of each position in the buffer array(avgArr[][]) (line 16). I'm thinking: the value of reds blues and greens would just be overwritten for each iteration and avgColor would just get the vlaue of the last pixel it got the rgb values off of avgArr.

```
    static ColorImage downscaleImg(ColorImage img, int f) {

    ColorImage dsi = new ColorImage(img.getWidth()/f, img.getHeight()/f);
    Color[][] avgArr = new Color[f][f];
    int reds = 0;
    int greens = 0;
    int blues = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < dsi.getWidth(); i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < dsi.getHeight(); j++) {
            for(int x = i*f, xc = 0; x < i*f + (f-1); x++, xc++){
                for(int y = j*f, yc = 0; y < j*f + (f-1); y++, yc++) {
                    avgArr[xc][yc] = img.getColor(x, y);
                }
            }
            for(int k = 0; k < f - 1; k++){
                for(int w = 0; w < f - 1; w++) {
                    reds += avgArr[k][w].getR();
                    greens += avgArr[k][w].getG();
                    blues += avgArr[k][w].getB();
                }
            }
            int count = f*f;
            Color avgColor = new Color(reds/count, greens/count, blues/count);
            dsi.setColor(i, j, avgColor);
            reds = 0;
            greens = 0;
            blues = 0;
        }
    }
    return dsi;
}
```

Thanks,

EDIT: Turns out, it was in fact just taking the colour of, the last position of avgArr that it looked at. Any suggestions to correct are welcome.

Comment: You'd think they'd be overwritten for each iteration of *what*? There are six loops. In any case, yes, they get overwritten, but so what? You don't need them at the end of the outer loops (width, height). `avgColor` gets a new `Color` based on the calculations done in the *inner* pairs of nested loops.

Comment: So if I understand correctly - you have code that works and want to figure out why it’s not failing?

Comment: OP is (correctly) saying that the two loops using `k` and `w` might as well be replaced with `reds = avgArr[f-2][f-2].getR()` etc, since each iteration overwrites the previous values.

Comment: Apologies, overwritten for each iteration of the loops starting on line 16. so it would get the red blue and green values for the - example- [0][0] position of avgArr, and then get overwritten by the red blue and green values from the [0][1] position of avgArr

Comment: @KekMckek is it possible that using the last pixel, instead of an average of them, just happens to look "good enough" with whatever test images you're using?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm saying, but it still outputs correctly coloured images at the desired size which has me utterly confused because the colour values should be skewed by the fact it's only taking account one of the colours around the original pixel.

Comment: downscaled: https://i.imgur.com/yOrvaEP.png
original: https://i.imgur.com/wkjXl8Z.png

@AlexWitting I've considered the possibility, but I've tested it on multiple pictures. Doesn't look like from this, wouldn't the borders between colours be messed up by only looking at the last pixel?

Comment: Right, with those test images every block of pixels is overwhelmingly the exact same color, so the value of a single pixel is nearly always going to be exactly the same as averaging the whole block.

In other words, you are right about how your code (doesn't) work, it's just hard to tell with that test image.

Comment: Try an input image which alternates black and white pixels.  I think your code will turn it all black or all white, rather than gray.

Comment: Upon further attempts to unveil the issue that does appear to be it. When I try to use it on a decently high res portrait, this happens: https://i.imgur.com/V64At51.png

definitely does not look like the correct downscaling of the source photograph(wikipedia, official portrait).

Thank you for your help. Any suggestions in achieving correct averages for the pixels by any chance?

Comment: @AlexWittig and you're absolutely correct, I tried it and it came out all black.

Comment: Perhaps making red blues and greens f*f length arrays would solve my problem, no?

Comment: @KekMckek yes, you could do it with more arrays, or just sum them up during the loop and divide later to get the average.  See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem by *summing* the reds/greens/blues and then dividing them by the total pixels at the end to find the average:

```
int reds = 0;
int greens = 0;
int blues = 0;

...

        for(int k = 0; k < f - 1; k++){
            for(int w = 0; w < f - 1; w++) {
                reds += avgArr[k][w].getR();    // <-- note the +=
                greens += avgArr[k][w].getG();
                blues += avgArr[k][w].getB();
            }
        }

        int count = (f-1)*(f-1);
        Color avgColor = new Color(reds/count, greens/count, blues/count);
```

Comment: Thank  you. but it now throws an exception because blue is 278 on the 7th pixel down. which shouldn't be happening because it can't more than 255 out of any given position on the array and it's dividing by the number of positions in avgArr.
edit: not just blues, other components too in other images.

Comment: Hmm... I don't think that should be possible with the code I provided.  Can you add your updated code to the question?

Comment: Figured it out kinda: the component values weren't resetting, so it kept adding to them every j loop, until it "overflowed". Solved by setting reds/greens/blues to zero every j loop. Now it outputs, except the image is quite darkened.

Comment: Oh right, you will need to reset to zero.  Good call.

Comment: I think it's expected that the resulting image will be darker.  Averaging colors doesn't produce very good results since "average" colors are brownish/grayish.  You will need to use more advanced sampling techniques.  (Ironically, the sampling technique you accidentally wrote in the first place is better in some respects since it preserves real colors from the original!)

Comment: Ah it was my fault, I set count = f*f instead of count = (f-1) * (f-1). Why is this the correct option? Wouldn't for example for a 2 factor downscale, avgArr be 2x2 and the total amount of getR()'s be 4 per pixel? Or this somehow to do with how rgb colours are averaged?

Comment: Ah so it seems to be rgb's fault(typed last comment before seeing yours) but (f-1) did fix it. Thanks for helping, it's much appreciated.

Comment: I used `(f-1)` because your `k` and `w` loops are each looping `f-1` times, therefore you are checking `(f-1)*(f-1)` pixels.  I didn't want to confuse the issue by mentioning it, but that's likely a bug and you just want `f`.  You are skipping a row and column of pixels the way you have it.

Comment: But looping k and w for f times results in a NullPointerException when it tries to get, keeping the example above, avgArr[0][2], because there's only 2 rows and zero indexing. But (f-1) results in correct image brightness so I'll keep that, but I find it rather odd.

Comment: You also have `f-1` in your `x` and `y` loops which would need to change.
Also, be careful of your integer division in `img.getWidth()/f` and `img.getHeight()/f`.  If those result in a remainder you may have unexpected results.